# Connecting to a WSE 3.0 Web Service From a WCF Client

Tags: wcf, web-services, wse

I'm having difficulty connecting to a 3rd party WSE 3.0 web service from a WCF client.  I have implemented the custom binding class as indicated in this KB article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734745.aspx

The problem seems to have to do with the security assertion used by the web service - UsernameOverTransport.

When I attempt to call a method, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   'WseHttpBinding'.'[namespace]'
>   binding for the
>   'MyWebServiceSoap'.'[namespace]'
>   contract is configured with an
>   authentication mode that requires
>   transport level integrity and
>   confidentiality. However the transport
>   cannot provide integrity and
>   confidentiality..

It is expecting a username, password, and CN number.  In the example code supplied to us by the vendor, these credentials are bundled in a Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken.  Here's the example supplied by the vendor:

```
MyWebServiceWse proxy = new MyWebServiceWse();

UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("Username", "password", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);

token.Id = "<supplied CN Number>";

proxy.SetClientCredential(token);

proxy.SetPolicy(new Policy(new UsernameOverTransportAssertion(), new RequireActionHeaderAssertion()));

MyObject mo = proxy.MyMethod();
```

---

This works fine from a 2.0 app w/ WSE 3.0 installed.  Here is a snippet of the code from my WCF client:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("<web service uri here>"));

WseHttpBinding binding = new WseHttpBinding(); // This is the custom binding I created per the MS KB article

binding.SecurityAssertion = WseSecurityAssertion.UsernameOverTransport;
binding.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

// Not sure about the value of either of these next two
binding.RequireDerivedKeys = true;
binding.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;

MembershipServiceSoapClient proxy = new MembershipServiceSoapClient(binding, address);

// This is where I believe the problem lies – I can’t seem to properly setup the security credentials the web service is expecting 

proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";
// How do I supply the CN number?                      

MyObject mo = proxy.MyMethod(); // this throws the exception
```

I've scoured the web looking for an answer to this question.  Some sources get me close (like the MS KB article), but I can't seem to get over the hump.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just to make sure, does your third party know that WSE is obsolete?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? Does anyone have an idea? I'm currently stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

I had success in a similar case with the following binding configuration:

```
<bindings>
   <customBinding>
      <binding name="FNCEWS40MTOMBinding">
         <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                   allowInsecureTransport="true" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
         </security>
         <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004"
                              maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
         <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
     </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is refering to **Transport Level** Security, this usually means https.

You have not shown your configuration files. But I am guessing that you have configured security to be transport (or it is required as a consiquence of another choice) and used an address that is http instead of https.

Comment: Hi Shiraz, thanks for responding.  I am defining the SecurityAssertion as UserNameOverTransport programatically in the code I provide above.  The web service does not use https, so I do not believe that this is the problem.

Comment: I think that this is why you are getting the error. You are sending the username/password over the transport, WCF then sees that the password will go over the wire unencrypted and refuses to start the service.

Comment: It seems that would be a major difference between WSE3.0 and WCF, then. I can use a WSE 3.0 client without SSL to connect to my WSE3 service, but a WCF client won't connect with the same message Dave got in his sample.